# How do I run an Apollo graphQL query before the App component is first rendered? (_and depends on it_)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, graphql, apollo

I need to call an Apollo query and the App component depends on its result, so how can I accomplish that?
I specifically want to redirect the user to a page based on their privileges.
I can't figure out how or where to call the query.

File `App.tsx`

```js
    // ...
    client = new ApolloClient({
      cache: new InMemoryCache(),
      link: ApolloLink.from([authMiddleware, errorlink, httpLink]),
      credentials: 'include',
    });

    export const App: FC = () => {
      // This doesn't work, I guess because it's not "inside" the ApolloProvider
      const { loading, error, data: { user } } = useQuery<{ user: User }>(whoAmIQuery);

      // this doesn't work either because I can't define the React.FC as an async function
      const result = await client.query({query: whoAmIQuery});

      return (
        <div className="app">
          <CookiesProvider>
            <Router history={browserHistory}>
              <ApolloProvider client={client}>
                <Suspense fallback={<div />}>
                  <Switch>
                    <Route path="/login" exact>
                      <LoginPage />
                    </Route>
        <!-- ... -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of loading state provided by useQuery.
Wrap your App.tsx in another component or file like bootstrap.tsx

bootstrap.tsx

```
export const RenderApp: FC = () => {
  //Initialize your client here...

  return (
     <ApolloProvider client={client}>
         <App/>
     </ApolloProvider>
  );
```

App.tsx

```
   export const App: FC = () => {
      // This doesn't work, I guess, because it's not "inside" the ApolloProvider
      const { loading, error, data: { user } } = useQuery<{ user: User }>(whoAmIQuery);

      // this doesn't work either because I can't define the React.FC as an async function
      const result = await client.query({query: whoAmIQuery});

  return (
    <>
      {loading && <div>Loading state</div>}
      {!loading && data && (
        <div>Your Code</div>
      )}
      {!loading && error && <div>Error state</div>}
    </>
  );
```

Comment: As the comment suggests, I can't use `useQuery` there, it throws an error about some invariant.

Comment: I have edited the answer please take a look